# How to disable automatic shut-down on low power (Ubuntu 15.04)?

Tags: 15.04, power-management, shutdown, battery

So apparently there's a nasty bug on my laptop (an Acer Aspire 3810T) that makes Ubuntu freak out when plugging/unplugging power. Frequently, it claims the battery is at 0% when switching power sources, and it's getting to the point where it's interfering with my work. This last time, it was at 95% when I plugged it back in, and while it was connected to the power brick, it shut down due to "critical battery" and showed 0% remaining. Which... I know better.

So I'd like to just simply disable its automatic shutdown altogether so's to prevent further disruption. Frankly, I'd rather my computer not be doing certain things automatically anyways... and shutting down is one of those things.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
sudo dconf-editor
```

if you haven't it, then install:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

then

> org->gnome->settings-daemon->plugins->power->critical-battery-action=>nothing