# How to disable automatic shutdown due to "critical temperature" on Lubuntu 32bits?

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, temperature

I have recently installed Lubuntu on an old Acer 4310 notebook alongside a windows 10 copy. The problem is that it will automatically shut down while on Lubuntu due to "critical temperature" for what I can read before it turns off. The thing is, the computer isn't very hot at all.. it's quite normal and isn't even under heavy load. This has never happened with windows despite taxing the hardware much more!

The message is displayed on the next line after the fsck line after quitting the desktop environment and instants before shutting down.

Any ideas on what I can do or how to disable it? I have ALREADY opened it and the computer and fan are clean.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a BIOS thing? Don't know, just guessing. Maybe you can tweak temperature limits or fan control parameters there.

Comment: I have cheked but there is no option to change fan behaviour or temperature control.

Comment: Sounds more like a defect sensor. What is the readout on the sensors?

Comment: I don't know how to see that.

Comment: Look at the settings in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668606/how-to-disable-automatic-shut-down-on-low-power-ubuntu-15-04). Maybe one of them will address it

Comment: And [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605378/how-can-i-disable-enable-ubuntus-auto-shut-down-feature) seems similar.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It seems to me like the computer is just old and the chipset has bad thermal management. This problem isn't relevant to me anymore, but I'm sure your comments will help somebody else in the future. Cheers.